# Ordering Headers in a DataFrame using Python

Tags: python, header, dataframe, pandas

How do I order the headers of a dataframe.

```
from pandas import *
import pandas
import numpy as np
df2 = DataFrame({'ISO':['DE','CH','AT','FR','US'],'Country': 
['Germany','Switzerland','Austria','France','United States']})
print df2
```

The result I get on default is this:

```
         Country ISO
0        Germany  DE
1    Switzerland  CH
2        Austria  AT
3         France  FR
4  United States  US
```

But I thought the ISO would be before the Country as that was the order i created it in the dataframe. It looks like it sorted it alphabetically?

How can i set up this simple table in memory to be used later in relational queries in my preferred column order. Everytime i reference the dataframe i dont want to have to order the columns.

My first coding post ever, ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dict has no ordering, you can use *columns* argument to enforce one. If *columns* is not provided, default ordering is indeed alphabetically.

```
In [2]: df2 = DataFrame({'ISO':['DE','CH','AT','FR','US'],
   ...:                  'Country': ['Germany','Switzerland','Austria','France','United States']},
   ...:                  columns=['ISO', 'Country'])

In [3]: df2
Out[3]:
  ISO        Country
0  DE        Germany
1  CH    Switzerland
2  AT        Austria
3  FR         France
4  US  United States
```

Answer (score 1):

a Python [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) is unordered. The keys are not stored in the order you declare or append to it. The `dict` you give to the `DataFrame` as argument has an arbitrary order the DataFrame takes for granted.

You have several options to circumvent the issue:

1. Use a [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) object instead of the `dict` if you really need a dictionary as an input:

   `df2 = DataFrame(OrderedDict([('ISO',['DE','CH','AT','FR','US']),('Country',['Germany','Switzerland','Austria','France','United States'])]))`
2. If you don't rely on a dictionary in the first place, then call the `DataFrame` with arguments declaring the columns:

   `df2 = DataFrame({'ISO':['DE','CH','AT','FR','US'],'Country': 
   ['Germany','Switzerland','Austria','France','United States']}, columns=['ISO', 'Country'])`